# Programmatic instantiation of Maven Mojo?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

Within a Mojo how can I progammatically get Mojo instances of other POM files?

In my use case I have a Mojo X which allows to declare references to other artifacts Y in the POM (let's say similar to the Depencency Plugin's artifactItems).

When X executes I want to see whether Y's POM has also plugin X configured.  If this is the case, I want to parse out configuration values of plugin X from POM Y.

My code so far is able to resolve Y's POM and construct a Model.  I'm now looking into fiddling with Xpp3Dom to parse out the configuration values.  This seems stupid.  Instead I'd like to use Maven's POM-to-Mojo mapping mechanism.

I'm just unclear how to instantiate a Mojo "by hand".
-Max

Comment: So, you're writing a plugin? In Java? It sounds like you're parsing the POM, don't do that :) If you have `@Component` `private MavenProject project;` in your plugin, that should give you all the access you need?

Comment: I'm not parsing the POM which the plugin is configured to! I need to parse *other* POMs which the plugin configuration references.

Comment: The [maven-plugin-testing-harness](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/plugin-testing.html) seems to point into the desired direction.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the following gives you a more reliable way to parse other POMs:

```
Reader reader = new FileReader(pomXmlFile);
MavenXpp3Reader xpp3Reader = new MavenXpp3Reader();
Model model = xpp3Reader.read(reader);
```

This was taken from [A Java Developer's Life](http://javadeveloperslife.wordpress.com/2009/10/12/parsing-a-maven-pom/).

Comment: I don't see how this shows how a specific Mojo gets instantiated. The POM in question has configured a Maven plugin X.  I want the instance of Mojo X, so I don't have to parse out the X config in the POM by hand.

Comment: You asked about parsing out configuration values. That seems to be your end goal, not instantiating a plugin. Perhaps clarify your question rather than downvoting me :)